# How to handle the reveal action after hits the cancel button in popup

Tags: java, gwt, gwtp, gwt-platform

When I click a add link it opens a popup and I cancel the popup then it goes to the previous place.

```
private class CancelHandler implements ClickHandler {
    @Override
    public void onClick(ClickEvent event) {
        if (popupPanel != null) {
            popupPanel.hide();
            getUiHandlers().getPlaceManager().revealPreviousPlace();
            //I added this code, after the popup closes, the url is not resetting. So I revealed to the previous place.
        }
    }
}
```

One list page shows a list of records, Here one validation is handled i.e If there is only one record in a list page it will automatically reveal to the display page. In display page (i.e popup) cancel button is present, If I hits the cancel button it is cancelling but it again opens the display page. If I comment the below line of the code `(getUiHandlers().getPlaceManager().revealPreviousPlace();)`, It is not opening, but I want that line for this purpose, after clicking cancel button I need to reset the url for that I am revealing the request to previous place.
Can anyone say how to fix this issue?

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know `PlaceManager#revealPreviousPlace()` doesn't exist.

I don't know the exact behavior you are looking for. If all you want to do is go back to the previous URL, you can call `com.google.gwt.user.client.History.back()`. Note that this is the same as the user clicking the browser's back button. For more safety, I would recommend having the cancel action always redirect to the same place.